# How to pass parameter in Store to web api

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How can we pass a parameter in store. I am new to ExtJs pls suggest me.

```
 xtype: 'grid',
store: {
type: 'webapi',
//extraParams: {
    //ID: 20
//},
 //Params: {
   //ID: 20
//},
api: {
    read: 'api/Report/GetInfo'
},
autoLoad: true,
},
columns: [
{ header: 'All', xtype: 'checkcolumn', dataIndex: 'flag', width: '10%' },
{ header: 'Code', dataIndex: 'code', width: '15%' },
{ header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', width: '15%' },    
{ header: 'State', dataIndex: 'state', width: '15%' }   
],
```

Tried by using `Params` and `extraPrams` but no success.

Comment: Try adding `extraParams` to the proxy, not to the store.

Comment: By the way, where did you find `store:'webapi'` in the docs?

Comment: After made the change from store > proxy - it is not calling web api. Do i need to change anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this way:

```
xtype     : 'grid',
store     : {
    type    : 'webapi',
    proxy   : {
        type       : "ajax",
        extraParams: {
            ID: 20
        }
    },
    api     : {
        read: 'api/Report/GetInfo'
    },
    autoLoad: true
}
```

Or you could add extra params in your grid in initComponent() function:

```
initComponent: function(){
    var me = this,
        myId = 20;
    me.callParent(arguments);       
    var    store = me.getStore();
    store.getProxy().extraParams = {
        ID:myId
    }
}
```

Comment: initComponent logic worked perfectly for me.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        ...
    proxy : {

            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'url',
            reader : {
                rootProperty : 'data',
            }
        },
        listeners:{
            beforeload: function(store){
         Ext.apply(this.proxy.extraParams, {
                    "ID" : 20
                });
            }
        },
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested but no success :(